# How to elute the protein that is bound to biotinylated RNA immobilized with streptavidin?

Tags: biochemistry, rna, protein-binding

I would like to test the proteins that bind to biotinylated-RNA by mass spectrometry , I was using Dynabeads™ MyOne™ Streptavidin C1 (invitrogen) coupled with biotinylated-RNA,than mix these beads up with cell lysate to achieve protein-RNA interacted solution, so does anybody know the better idea to elute that protein out of the mixed reagent?

Comment: What does the manual say about elution?

Comment: It doesn't have any info about elution

Comment: If your end goal is mass spec, you could do an on-bead digestion of the protein. Alternatively you could elute the protein with SDS buffer and do the digest in a gel. It should also be possible to break the protein-RNA interaction (eg with salt, cosolvents, and/or pH)

Comment: any specific protocol or detail with it?